# How to access server rendered HTML in Vue JS component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

Is there any way to get server rendered HTML in Vue JS component?

I have a component called `MathComponent` that displays a text on the screen using mathematical formula. But I don't want it to hydrate like other components. Rather, **I want to display the output generated by the server instead of regenerating it.** In this way, I can prevent the execution of that mathematical formula in client side.

I really want to do this. So please don't take my time by saying "executing a mathematical formula doesn't have much effect on website performance" or anything similar.

Thank you

Comment: **I want to display the output generated by the server instead of regenerating it.** What do you mean? What exactly is this output? How is this formule defined?

Comment: Do you just want v-html? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vue-js-v-html-directive/

Comment: Not at all. Please read the question again.

Comment: SSR returns an HTML to browser right? I just want to access it in my `MathComponent` and instead of rendering `MathComponent` again, return server side rendered HTML for `MathComponent`.

Comment: @viking you need v-html anyway

Comment: @viking check my answer, updated, you need to render your initial component in the `v-else` section

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render a usual HTML from the server, use `fetch` to fetch it from the backend, and display with `v-html` and `v-if`/`v-else`:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const html = ref('');

async function loadHtml() {
  html.value = await fetch('/your-url').then(r => r.text())
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="loadHtml">Load html</button>

  <div v-if="html" v-html="html"></div>
  <div v-else>
    Your component here until you update from the backend.
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have upvoted this because I think this is the answer OP needs but not wants. @viking, Why didn't you accept? Do you still think v-html is **not** what you want?